# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE module not found. What's wrong?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I'm pretty new to React and JavaScript, but I've been having a seriously frustrating issue. My NPM start command doesn't seem to work when I run it. I've tried to run `npm install` after deleting the node_modules folder, but I haven't had any luck. If anyone has a solution I would really appreciate the help.

See the error message below.

```
 ass1@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Chris Conrad\Documents\_GIT\Udemy\React\Section 3 Understanding Base Features & Syntax\ass1
> react-scripts start

'Syntax\ass1\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Chris Conrad\Documents\_GIT\Udemy\React\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ass1@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ass1@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chris Conrad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-21T00_32_03_270Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Chris Conrad\Documents\_GIT\Udemy\React\Section 3 Understanding Base Features & Syntax\ass1>
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ass1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your package.json

Comment: Just added the file. thank you

Comment: Interesting. Usually that only happens if you moved directories. Generally speaking, EACH React "project" requires its own install of node_modules assuming you use npm, not yarn. Yet it doesn't look like you're setup that way, nor do you seem to be using create-react-app. So what is your "toolchain" setup for reactjs?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but I actually did use the Create-React_App. I've found that I only have the issue now when I use create-react-app in that specific folder for some reason